# Rich Snippet on homepage

Tags: microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

We have embedded rich snippets for a rental objects rating website. Here an example:

http://www.google.de/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sonnenquartiere.de%2Fferienwohnungen%2F4-wohnung-8-boardinghaus-norderney-2-zimmer-apartment.html

Works fine when listed in Google search results.

Now we want to aggregate all ratings and post them on the homepage so the homepage itself gets a rating in the Google search results. We did it some time ago:
http://www.google.de/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=www.sonnenquartiere.de

We did that some time ago, but the result in the Google Search is still not being displayed with the aggregated rating. Here an Example:

https://www.google.de/search?q=Boardinghaus+Norderney (2nd place here)

Is there something we can do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I did notice about your markup is that you are using the schema.org/WebPage markup for your aggregate review rating.  So search engines are seeing that schema as a rating for your home page.  You should be using the aggregate rating schema with a schema that better describes your type of business, perhaps something in the schema.org/LodgingBusiness category.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not too late and that I will be able to help.

Following the standard procedure is the best practice in such thing. Make sure you use the correct markup. So for review use the reviews-schema as the example below:

Use this tool to generate the code and then modify your website according to this working sample
http://www.microdatagenerator.com/reviews-schema/

For example:

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope temtype="http://schema.org/Thing"><span itemprop="name">home mortgage</span> </div>
    <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">  
     <span itemprop="name"> Nick M.</span>
      </div><meta itemprop="datePublished" content = "01/01/2016"> 
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope   itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" 
    <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/><span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span>/<span itemprop="bestRating">5</span> stars   </div>
          <span itemprop="description">My experience with ABC Company was very good and I recommend it to everyone.  </span>
             </div>
```

you take that code and take the parts you need to your webpage.

This video was great:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2PjWtybDOs